# Strategies for finding a model in order to generate synthetic data

Tags: r, time-series, arima, dataset, bootstrap

This is my problem: using R. I need to generate data from a time-series without storing the historical data since they could not be available in some cases, so my objective is to find a *generic* model from which create a dataset similar (considering the statistical properties and the behaviour) to the starting one and *if necessary* do some transformations in order to change some statistical properties (but this is not a serious problem).

Until now, I explored different paths but the results were not so good:

1. **ARIMA MODEL** - slow but it gave me a model for each of the three time series's components (trend, noise, seasonality), however since the `arima.sim` command takes randomly, points from a user-defined function, using this strategy, I will lose all the relationships between time stamps and data. The results for the trend and seasonality components seem to be extremely bad and far from what I need, while for the noise it works quite well.
2. **BLOCK BOOTSTRAP** - quite useful but I need to store the whole dataset in my generator and for the final version it will not be possible.
3. **ECDF and Histograms** - I found something about the possibility to generate a dataset using one of these two objects but still it's not so clear to me how to do that.

Are there other strategies for creating a model useful for my purpose? Is there something about these three strategies that I didn't take in account?